# Install docky in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: repository, 20.04, docky, gdebi

I tried to install Docky from the official repositories via apt-get but it couldn't find the packet. So I downloaded the .deb from the web and tried a manual install with gdebi and this was the output:

```
$ sudo gdebi docky_2.2.1.1-1_all.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libgconf2.0-cil (>= 2.24.0)
```

I couldn't find any info about why this packet is not usable. Is there any other way to install docky?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to get [the dependencies](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/docky) of `docky` manually from previous Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/docky
cd ~/Downloads/docky

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-sharp2/libgconf2.0-cil_2.24.2-4_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring-common_3.12.0-1build1_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libg/libgnome-keyring/libgnome-keyring0_3.12.0-1build1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-keyring-sharp/libgnome-keyring1.0-cil_1.0.0-5_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

and then install docky:

```
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/docky/docky_2.2.1.1-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./docky_2.2.1.1-1_all.deb
```

Comment: Excelent! It works! Thank you very much. Any clue why those were taken out of the official repositories for 20.04?
PD: my reputation is too low to upvote your answer srry

Comment: Its project page on https://launchpad.net/docky is not updated since 2016, so seems to become obsolete.

Comment: Great! Thank you, have been trying to get Docky to work for weeks. An up vote from me!

Comment: Thanks! It works even for Ubuntu 22.04!

Comment: Thanks! It works on Linux Mint 21.1 Vera

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice extension [Dock from Dash](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4703/dock-from-dash/)
that completely replaces buggy and unsupported Docky on Ubuntu 22!

Comment: This is good information, but it doesn't answer the question.