# I want to install Docky. How to remove "Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu focal Release 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]"?

Tags: docky

I want to install "Docky" on Ubuntu 20.04 but, every time I try to add the source repository, I receive an error.

This is how I'm trying to add the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/stable
```

This is the result:

```
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                               
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                             
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                         
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu focal Release                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                      
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease    
Hit:8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: The PPA does not appear to be maintained anymore as the last update was [over four years ago](https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/ubuntu/stable). That said, [you may be able to use this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1237413/1222991) to install Docky on your system 

Comment: Docky is no longer maintained. I would suggest latte dock as it has all of the same features as far as I'm aware. You should be warned if you use the answer linked by @matigo that it could break your system because those dependencies are for another version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Nmath you have no confidence in N0rbert's answer? That, too, was for 20.04 (though the dependencies are for 18.04) 

Comment: @matigo I'm sure it *works*, but when you pull in dependencies from an older version of Ubuntu, the longer you cling to unmaintained software, the higher the chances that some new software needs a dependency that conflicts with the one you manually installed an older version of. This is a matter of *can do* vs *should do*.  IMO there's no good reason to force unmaintained software and potentially conflicting dependencies when there exists well maintained software that does exactly the same thing

Comment: You can also use Plank, which is made with GTK (unlike Latte dock, which is for KDE).

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file

Comment: It is a good point to use Plank if you are using GNOME since it will require fewer dependencies with that DE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install docky in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237396/install-docky-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)