# Docky on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, docky

I'm trying to install Docky on my machine. But I get an error saying `E: Unable to locate package docky`

How can I fix that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install docky in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237396/install-docky-in-ubuntu-20-04) Note that Docky is not maintained anymore, and was dropped from the official repositories. You can try Plank instead. `sudo apt install plank`.

Comment: You can do it as described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237396/install-docky-in-ubuntu-20-04
It works for both 'Ubuntu 20.04' and 'Ubuntu 22.04'.